# $y'(t) + 2ty(t) = e^{-t/2} \sin{t}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

## Problem

$$y'(t) + 2ty(t) = e^{-t/2} \sin{t}$$ with $y(0) = 0$

I tried to let $u(t) = e^{t^2} y(t)$, so that the function becomes
$$
u'(t) = e^{t^2-t/2} \sin t
$$
and then I cannot calculate this integral.

Anybody has another suggestion?

Comment: @Moo hi, would you mind explain it a little further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is too long for a comment.*

If you are limited to elementary functions, as Isaac Browne answered, you cannot go beyond $$u(t) = \int e^{t^2-t/2} \sin(t) dt$$ If you are not, use $$\sin(t)=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$$ which makes the integrand to be $$\frac{1}{2} i e^{t^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right) t}-\frac{1}{2} i
   e^{t^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\right) t}$$ Now, for the first term, complete the square $$t^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right) t=\left(t-\frac 12\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)\right)^2-\frac 14\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)^2=\left(t-\frac 12\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)\right)^2-\left(\frac{3}{16}-\frac{i}{4}\right)$$ Now, changing variable $$t-\frac 12\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right)=ix \implies dt=i\, dx$$ would make the first integral to be $$\int\frac{1}{2} i e^{t^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\right) t}\,dt=-\frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{3}{16}-\frac{i}{4}}\int e^{-x^2}\,dx$$ where you see appearing the gaussian integral.

The same process for the second integral.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason you cannot calculate the integral. The reason is that it cannot be written in closed form. There are actually quite a few integrals like this, such as $\int e^{-x^2}$, and it is best to just leave them in integral form.

Disclaimer: You can still find cool properties of these functions and sometimes you can write them as power series, such as in the case of $e^{-x^2}$, which can be a good exercise!

(Hint: remember the Taylor series of $e^x$)

Although something similar could be done in this problem, I would not suggest it, as it leads to the hassle of multiplying together infinite sums, a long and tedious process.

All things said, just write the solution in integral form.
$$u(t) = \int e^{t^2-t/2} \sin(t) dt$$